# Reference Help: Matsuki duality Orbits

Tags: reference-request, rt.representation-theory, lie-groups, algebraic-groups

I'm  studying the Matsuki duality of  $G_0$-orbits  and $K$-orbits over a flag manifold $G/P$ where $G$ is semisimple complex Lie group and $P$ is a parabolic subgroup. I would like to study some relations and topological properties about these orbits. I read some result from J.A.Wolf on the existence and uniqueness of a minimal dimension orbit.
Can someone please give me similar references?

Comment: $K$ orbits on $G/P$ are studied in the book if Adams-Barbasch-Vogan: The Langlands Classification and Irreducible Characters for Real Reductive Groups.